# Не получается использовать Toolbar для ActionBar во Фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

В Приложении есть Активность, в которой используется [Bottom Navigation Bar](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B3321sZLoP_HTTA0QUM4MWxKSTg/components_bottomnavigation_behavior_crossfade.webm), которая переключает 3 фрагмента. Так вот, в одном из них хочу поставить `ActionBar`, для чего использую в разметке фрагмента `Toolbar`, а наполнение идет из main_menu. Проблема в том, что не получается - `Toolbar` отображается, но не заполняется. Причем я попробовал это сделать в Активности - там все сработало.

Код как сработало в Активности:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Код как я пытаюсь это сделать во Фрагменте:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

    }
```

В приложении использую тему NoActionBar.

Comment: Вы что-то странное делаете. Зачем вам ещё раз назначать тулбар актионБаром?

Comment: А почему еще раз?

Comment: Вы же уже в активити это сделали... И вообще я не уверен, что то как вы тулбар во фрагменте ищете работает

Comment: В приложении в Активити у меня тулбар не назначается актионбаром, мне это надо для Фрагмента. Код с Активити я привел просто как пример того что для Активности у меня получилось назначить тулбар актионБаром(ну просто как эксперемент) а вот во Фрагменте что то не идет...

Comment: Если такой способ установки актионБаром через использование тулбара не работает. Каким еще способом можно добавить в Фрагмент АктионБар?

Comment: Поместите тулбар в разметку фрагмента

Comment: Он там есть проблема в том как его заполнить элементами из файла меню main_menu

Comment: Если тулбар у вас в разметке фрагмента то именно там его и надо найти и именно его назначить в качестве actiionBar-а.

Comment: Так это сделано:  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar); ___ или чтото в этих двух строчках кода неверно?

Comment: Так вы пытаетесь найти несуществующий тулбар в активити. Вам е надо во фрагменте. Т.е. в той разметке, что вы сразу после возвращаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищете тулбар в активити, а его там, по вашим словам нет. Ищите его в размтеке фрагмента

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_app_bar);
    //((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_training, container, false);

    View v = inflater.inflate(r.layout.fragment_training, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findviewbyid(r.id.my_app_bar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: спасибо! с Вашей помощью разобрался